# Wet HVAC condenser

Tags: wiring, hvac, weather-resistant

I’m in the process of having a Mitsubishi mini split system installed. The electrician wired the condenser and didn’t put the cover back on leaving all the electronics exposed to a torrential all night downpour. Will this be ok or should I make them replace the condenser? Thanks

Comment: Was the power on?  That usually is what causes the problems.  If power was off, leave off till everything is dry, if possible have a small fan blowing air for a day or two.

Comment: On the systems I have worked on the boards have a protective coating that prevents moisture from being a problem. If you are concerned take some photos. Mention it to the tech I doubt they would replace them, however if something did happen to go wrong you have evidence to support any claim.

Answer (score 6):

If it's being installed by approved Mitsubishi contractors, it's under warranty, so if it fails due to the rain exposure that's on them. [ *If they are not approved Mitsubishi contractors, it's still on them, but more of a pain since you're dealing with the contractor standing behind their work, as opposed to the manufacturer standing behind the product and approved installation.* ]

You don't need to make them replace it "on suspicion." It will be fine, or not.

Given that they operate in fog, etc. and end up wet inside, likely not as much of an issue as you're thinking, though sounds like somewhat sloppy workmanship to not put the cover back on.

Comment: Contact them, if they ignore you, then you could get there attention by posting photos on social media.